# Swift 3 Current Location to Simple location between MKPolyline

Tags: swift, swift2, mapkit, core-location, swift3

Hello i have working codes for current location blue dot show and simple location pin show I want to do line between them with MKPolyline my clear codes under below.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ShowMapViewController:  UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate ,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    var showmapListcomming = String()
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true


        // Show Map

        var myStringArrctakes = showmapListcomming.components(separatedBy: ",")


        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = (myStringArrctakes[6] as NSString).doubleValue
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = (myStringArrctakes[5] as NSString).doubleValue
        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 30
        let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 30
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let locations:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locations, span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)

        annotation.coordinate = locations
        annotation.title = myStringArrctakes[1]
        annotation.subtitle = "\(myStringArrctakes[2])"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    }

    // MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate methods

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView()
        return annotationView
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        if let location = locations.last {
            print("Found User's location: \(location)")
            print("Latitude: \(location.coordinate.latitude) Longitude: \(location.coordinate.longitude)")

        }



    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Failed to find user's location: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

I think easy but I didn't resolve it. Im waiting your ideas , I think will be help many people so in swift 3 I didn't find anything like this on web.

Thanks

Comment: Out of context but you dont need this code   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() and also set mapView delegate to self... mapView.delegate = self

Comment: @anishparajuli can you post answer with code.? I will check ty

Comment: ok here it is https://github.com/anishparajuli555/MapViewSwift3.git